# Usage of article "the"

Tags: grammar, british-english, definite-articles

> What kind of animal is the dodo ?

Is article *the* right in this question?

Comment: It's correct, but *a* would also be acceptable.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the [basic uses](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers/definite-article) of the definite article is to indicate you are talking about something as an archetype of a whole class of things. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may be of interest to you.

Comment: Because *a* is **also** correct, we need to know what you want your sentence to mean. The choice of article (much like the choice of preposition) can change the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact, We put the definite article 'the' before a singular noun of an animal to **denote the whole species** (the + singular noun) can represent a class of animals or things.
A dog is a loyal animal.  =  All dogs are loyal.

Comment: You explain the use of the definite article, but your example sentence doesn't use it.